# Pointer to function with template arguments

Tags: c++, function, templates, pointers, c++11

How do I create this, without creating a structure?

```
template <class T>
typedef bool (* FunctionPointer)(T*, T*);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `using`:

```
template <class T>
using FunctionPointer = bool (*)(T*, T*);
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/WnlFh0)

Comment: Even better: `template <class T> using Function = bool(T*, T*)`, and then you can spell out `Function * p`. It's polite not to hide pointers in type aliases...